# Disable @typescript-eslint/naming-convention for imported types

Tags: eslint

What would be a strategy not to apply the `@typescript-eslint/naming-convention` rule to types imported from 3rd-party libraries? It's pretty common to have to deal with types that we have no control over, and that contain names that don't adhere to our own conventions. At times this can be a lot of different names, so we would like to avoid using `// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/naming-convention` every other line of code.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I'm also looking into this now. `zod` for some reason is using `snake_case`.

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer on GitHub issues, although it might not be what you're looking for.

You can selectively ignore certain names from being enforced in the naming convention. Here's an example setup:

```json
"@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
  "warn",
  {
    selector: "property",
    format: ["camelCase"],
  },
  {
    selector: "property",
    format: null,
    filter: {
      regex: "(required_error|invalid_type_error)",
      match: true,
    },
  },
],
```

The first rule makes it necessary for all properties to be in `camelCase`. The second rule adds exceptions to that case. In our particular scenario, we're using Zod, and Zod has properties in objects accepted by methods that are cased like `required_error` and `invalid_type_error`.

You can also compose a list of ignores using:

```
const ignoredPropNames = `^(${[
  'name_one',
  'NameTwo',
  ...
].join('|')})$`;
```

[Here is the full discussion.](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2147) Anyhow, hope this helps!